# download.file - curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: r, curl, libcurl

I know variations of this question have been posted elsewhere in different forums, but I swear I've navigated all those questions and read all possible documentation to no avail.

I have a PC with Ubuntu 18. I need to get files regularly from SFTP server, so I re-installed curl with openssl compatibility.

When I use in R `download.file(url = "sftp://...", destfile = "destfile", method = "curl")` I get `URL 'sftp://...': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'`.

The same happens if I launch on the terminal `curl -v sftp://sftpserver... --output destfile`:

```
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\*   Trying 51.\*\*.\*\*\*.\*\*\*:22...
\* Connected to sftpserver (51.\*\*.\*\*\*.\*\*\*) port 22 (#0)
\* Found host sftpserver in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
\* Set "ssh-rsa" as SSH hostkey type
\* SSH MD5 public key: NULL
\* SSH SHA256 public key: NULL
\* SSH host check: 2, key: \<none\>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
\* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I don't really understand the NULL/none values in the public key info, nor how to fix it (if that's indeed the problem).

However, if in R I change `method = "curl"` with `method = "libcurl"` the download proceeds without problem (I don't know how to replicate this on the terminal). Using the `-k` option (`--insecure`) to skip the SSL check I can download the file, but of course this is not ideal.

Now, the problem:

I have bought a new PC and installed Ubuntu 22.04. I again installed curl with openssl compatibility and still get error 60 on the terminal. The problem is that in R, in the new machine, the download fails with the same error **even if I use** `method = "libcurl"`.

About the CA certificates, the folder `/etc/ssl/certs/` looks the same on both computers. And I have downloaded the Mozilla certificate bundle from the curl website and run `sudo update-ca-certificates` on the new machine.

Any help on this will be more than welcome. Thanks.

As I said, I have tried to install and update the CA certificates. I also contacted the server maintainers and they told me that they just set the user/pwd and made sure that they don't have any IP restrictions. About the certificates, they said it's an Azure-based service for SFTP.

The only thing that works for me right now is using `method = "curl", extra = "-k"` parameters in `download.file` but it's far from ideal. I would like to be able to use `method = "libcurl"` like I did in the old machine.